# How to add a late fee automatically to a monthly payment(solidity)

Tags: solidity

I'm working on a smart contract that allows users to pay for monthly subscriptions like Netflix, Amazon, etc...

the function that allows user to pay their subscriptions is working fine, but I want to add an additional feature so when the user misses his monthly payment the amount that they should pay should increase.

How can I implement that inside the below function?

What do you think about the payment? it's secure enough?

```
 struct Plan {
        address merchant;
        address token;
        uint amount;
        uint frequency;
      }
      struct Subscription {
        address subscriber;
        uint start;
        uint nextPayment;
      }
      mapping(uint => Plan) public plans;
      mapping(address => mapping(uint => Subscription)) public subscriptions;
    
    function pay(address subscriber, uint planId) external {
        Subscription storage subscription = subscriptions[subscriber][planId];
        Plan storage plan = plans[planId];
        require(
          subscription.subscriber != address(0), 
          'this subscription does not exist'
        );
        require(
          block.timestamp > subscription.nextPayment,
          'not due yet'
        );
   require(msg.value >= plan.monthlyPayment, "monthly payment not correct");
     
        emit PaymentSent(
          subscriber,
          plan.merchant, 
          plan.amount, 
          planId, 
          block.timestamp
        );
        subscription.nextPayment = subscription.nextPayment + 4 weeks;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user calls the `pay` function, if he exceeded the deadline so

`if(block.timestamp > subscription.nextPayment)`

you calculate the additional fee based on the difference between `block.timestamp` and `subscription.nextPayment` so, the bigger is the time that passed after the payment deadline, the bigger is the difference and the bigger is the fee that the user has to pay in additional to the base amount.

Comment: Great Idea! Can you demonstrate it with code?